# combineLatest doesn't emit latest value

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I'm having difficulty wrapping my head around why `combineLatest` isn't returning the latest value.  This example is a bit contrived but at least it illustrates my problem.  Notice the value of `color` from the `combineLatest` observable returns a previous value, when the `subject.value` is correct. It's like the `color$` observable hasn't emitted.

```
import { map, distinctUntilChanged, combineLatest } from 'rxjs/operators'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

const main$ = new BehaviorSubject({color: 'red'});

const color$ = main$.pipe(
  map(state => state.color),
)

main$.pipe(
  combineLatest(color$)
)
.subscribe(([state, color]) => {
  console.log(state, color, main$.value.color);
})

main$.next({
    color: 'yellow'
});
```

**Actual Output**

```
{color: "red"} "red" "red"

{color: "yellow"} "red" "yellow"

{color: "yellow"} "yellow" "yellow"
```

**Expected Output**

```
{color: "red"} "red" "red"

{color: "yellow"} "yellow" "yellow"  // Notice middle value is yellow

{color: "yellow"} "yellow" "yellow"
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/combine-latest-issue

If someone could help explain whats going, and provide a workaround or proper way to think about this in `rxjs` I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be useful to visualize what is going on rather than words:

```
main$     R--------------------Y------------------------------

color$    -------R-----------------------Y---------------------

output    -----[R,R]---------[Y,R]-----[Y,Y]------------------
```

If you use `zip` instead of `combineLatest`, you will get very closer to what you expect. See bellow what happens if you use `zip`:

```
main$     R--------------------Y------------------------------

color$    -------R-----------------------Y---------------------

output    -----[R,R]-------------------[Y,Y]------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the visual this helps a lot

Answer (score 2):

First `main$` is updated, which feeds into the `combineLatest()` as a change but doesn't trigger output because `color$` hasn't emitted a value. Then `color$` computes its new value, emits it, and there are now two values available for `combineLatest()` and the first line of text is output.

Then `main$` is updated to `{color: "yellow"}`, feeds into the `combineLatest()` which takes the latest value from `main$` and the latest value from `color$` (which is still `"red"`, and triggers a new output of `{color: "yellow"} "red" "yellow"`.

Finally, `color$` is updated and triggers `combineLatest()` to issue the final line of output.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how I should refactor to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

Use Observable.zip instead of combineLatest, which emits the very closer values from the subjects. It works for me as expected.